# Using glArrayElement does not produce visible output

Tags: opengl

Can somebody tell me what is mistake here. It shows display window, but unfortunately doesn't draw a triangle.

```
#include<glut.h>
GLint vertices[] ={   /*vertex array */
    0.25, 0.25,
    -0.9, 0.8,
    0.5, -0.5
    -0.2, -0.8
};
GLfloat colors[]={   /*color array*/
    1.0, 0.0, 0.0,
    0.0, 1.0, 0.0,
    0.0, 0.0, 1.0,
    1.0, 1.0, 0.0 
};
void display(){
    glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glEnableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY); /* enabling color array*/
    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY); /*enableing vertex array */

    glColorPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, colors); 
    glVertexPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, vertices);

    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES); /* dereferencing */
    glArrayElement(0);  
    glArrayElement(1);
    glArrayElement(2);
    glEnd();

    glDisableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY); 
    glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glFlush(); 

}
void main() {
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGBA); 
    glutInitWindowPosition(200, 200);
    glutInitWindowSize(300,300);
    glutCreateWindow("My application");
    glutDisplayFunc(display); 
    glutMainLoop(); 
}
```

Comment: Your mistake was using `glArrayElement`. Seriously, never use this function for *anything*.

Comment: But it reduces number of calls functions. So you mean that by using glArrayElement i can't never get the result??? )))

Comment: Here's something that would *also* reduce the number of function calls: using `glDrawArrays` or `glDrawElements` instead of what you're doing. If you're going to use arrays, then *use arrays*.

Comment: @user2473729 *"So you mean that by using glArrayElement i can't never get the result?"* - You can, it's not that it won't work with `glArrayElement`. But you should stop trying because after this test program you won't *ever* want  to use it again (and it might very well be broken in the driver, considering the fact that *nobody ever* uses it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `vertices` array is of type `GLint[]`, so all the float (or rather double) values in the initialization expression will just be truncated to `0` and it won't match the type given in `glVertexPointer` either, causing whatever weird results (though in exactly this case the binary representations of all those integer `0`s are probably also the binary representations of a float `0.0f`). Given the use of `GL_FLOAT` in `glVertexPointer` you probably meant it to be `GLfloat vertices[]`.

(Side note: As noted in the comments the `glArrayElement` function is pretty useless and if you're already using vertex arrays, then you should actually draw them with a single array draw call instead of a million `glArrayElement` calls inside a `glBegin/glEnd` block, which is the whole purpose and advantage of arrays compared to `glBegin/glEnd`. So in fact your `glBegin/glEnd` block can be replaced by a simple `glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);`. But with the above mentioned correction of the array type it should at least work correctly.)